# Standby optimization in Aviation

Tags: optimization, heuristics

I am looking for a heuristic/exact algorithm to model this problem related to airport standby. The goal here is to suggest different standby slots required to cover all the flights leaving an airport.

Known data:

1. Number of standby needed for each day
2. The timings of the flights for a week

Constraints:

1. There will be some time constraints, like the rest between two duties, the duration of a duty etc.

My goal is to plan the standby slots so that all the flights are covered and the number of slots created is optimal.

Any idea how to approach this problem? Any links to articles/journals would also help.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways and technologies to model this. Given my bias, I 'll just show you how you would do it with Timefold (open source, java):

- This sounds a lot like shift scheduling, but the starting time of a shift is an optimization variable. So I would turn the model inside out: create shifts per employee (possibly too many shifts) and assign those starting times.
- With the information available, I think [the time grain pattern](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/design-patterns/design-patterns#assigningTimeToPlanningEntities) best suits your needs.
- For each day, for each employee create 1 Shift instance.
- Not every Shift needs to be assigned, some can be assigned to null. As long as all flights are covered with the non-null assigned shifts, it's good.

Then your model looks something like this:

```
@PlanningEntity class Shift {
   Employee employee;
   LocalDate date;
   Duration duration;
   @PlanningVariable(nullable=true) LocalTime start;

   LocalTime getEnd() { return start.plus(duration); }
}
class Employee {
   String id;
}
class Flight {
   String id;
   LocalTime departureStart;
   LocalTime departureEnd;
}
```

And your constraints something like this (pseudo code):

```
// All flights need to be covered
.forEach(Flight)
.ifNotExists(Shift,
    overlapping(Flight::departureStart, Flight::departureEnd,
        Shift::start, Shift::end)
.penalize(HARD).asConstraint("No shift to cover a flight", ...)

// Rest between two duties
.forEach(Shift)
.join(Shift, equals(Shift::employee))
.filter((shift1, shift2) -> Duration.between(shift1.end, shift2.end) > 0 && < 10 hours)
.penalize(HARD).asConstraint(, "Not enough rest between two shifts", ...)

// Minimize shifts
.forEach(Shift)
.penalize(SOFT).asConstraint("Minimize number of shifts")

// Optionally add a fairness constraint:
// loadBalance() the shifts across employees
...
```

This problem naturally flows across multiple days, so you'll need to apply [Continuous Planning](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/p6V7VdAYFIc) for execution.